# Android: Change text of a TextView that is inside a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, textview

I know that i could just refresh the ListView but i don't want it to jump to the very top again.

So i have got a ListView. In it there are a few TextViews, Buttons, ImageViews, etc. I filled it using a custom adapter and everything works fine. Even the OnClickListener for the Buttons. But as soon as i try to change the content of one of the TextViews like so (Button to increase the value of the number in the tv. This is called in the getView() of my adapter):

```
btn_inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        count.setText(Integer.parseInt(""+count.getText())+1);
    }
});
```

i get the following error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

I assume this is because the TexView is only created temporary and deleted as soon as the getView() of my adapter is finished?

Thanks in advance for any of your awnsers!

Comment: Use `String.valueOf()` method to show `int` in TextView

Comment: count.setText(number); It will try to find text with id as your number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
btn_inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        count.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(""+count.getText())+1));
    }
});
```

Basically you are trying to set an `int` as the text of the TextView which accepts a `String`. Converting the `int` to a `String` should get rid of that error. In this case, Android is taking that integer and trying to look up a resource ID which in this case doesn't exist.

Comment: Wow, this website is like a life support! It wasnt even 10 seconds until you responded. Thanks man ! 

btw i gotta wait 5 mins to accept the awnser...

Comment: @bearsmahoney I have a doubt that on button click same row textview value might not change. Because its a listview and count reference will be different for different row.

Comment: @DhavalPatel that's possible but I think it will only change if the Listview is refreshed/updated right? In this case the OP said they are not doing that.